# window.print() is closing automatically

Tags: javascript

I have a document that I'm trying to print using `windows.print()`. I append it to a window document, open the window and trigger the `window.print()` method. It opens a new window and tries to print the content. However, sometimes the window closes automatically as soon as it opens and stops the entire process. Please find my code below -

```
    let myWindow = window.open("", name, "width=" + rect.outerWidth() + ",height=" + rect.outerHeight());

    myWindow.document.write('<html>');
    myWindow.document.write('<body>');
    myWindow.document.write(downloadContent);
    myWindow.document.write('</body>');
    myWindow.document.write('</html>');
    setTimeout(() => {
               myWindow.document.title = name;
               myWindow.document.close();
               myWindow.focus();
               myWindow.print();
               myWindow.close();
     }, 500);
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with **only** the code you pasted?

Comment: That's the entire code I have. Also very strangely, it doesn't occur always. Say like 40% of the time the issue is occurring, but I can't afford to go with that sort of probability on my live website.